# Difficulty implementing the List collection in C#

Tags: c#, list, collections

So, I'm trying to implement a list for the first time. I will eventually use this in a three-tier design in which the list holds all results from a database query. I can't seem get the small project working.

```
namespace listTest

class Account
{
   public string fName {get; set;}
   public string lName {get; set;}

   public Account()
   {
   }

   public Account(string last, string first)
   {
      this.fName = first;
      this.lName = last;
   }

     public void LoadAccounts()
     {
        List<Account> Accounts = new List<Account>();
        Accounts.Add(new Account("firstName", "lastName"));
     }
 }
```

So, this is my Account class. I have to preface this by saying I have no idea if I am implementing this correctly.

```
private void getListBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Account newAccount = new Account();
   List<Account> Accounts = new List<Account>();
}
```

Here is where I hit the button to load the list. The idea here is to access the fName and lName values and change two labels on my form. The way I have it now everything compiles, but I get null values for fName and lName on my presentation layer. Am I doing this all wrong? I feel like the domain layer is the best place for the list. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code to load the data from the DB?  When you create a new `List`, it will be empty unless you add things to it (or copy it from an existing `List`).  All the code you posted is doing is creating a new List of type Account.

Comment: That comes later, right now I am just trying to get the strings "firstName" and "lastName" into my form class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a method which returns the `List<Account>` from your Database like this

```
 public List<Account> LoadAccounts()
 {
     List<Account> AccountsList = new List<Account>();

     // Get Accounts records from Database and add them into AccountsList as per your logic like this

     AccountsList.Add(myaccount);

     return AccountsList
 }
```

then you can use it on your presentation layer like this

```
 private void getListBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    List<Account> Accounts = LoadAccounts();

   // now you can access first name and last name of each records like this

   foreach(Account account in Accounts)
   {
     string firstName=account.fName ;
     string lastName=account.lName ;
   }
 }
```

Comment: I can't use List<Account> Accounts = LoadAccounts(); without instantiating an Account object. I messed with the code a bit but I still have null values.

Comment: Without Account anAccount = new Account() I cannot see the methods in the account class. I think this might be producing my null values.

Comment: why are you using `anAccount.fName` inside the foreach loop. it should simple `account.fName` as I described in my example. account is a variable which I used in foreach loop

Comment: I apologize, I have no idea why that was there. I think it was giving me an error and I changed it. The code you provided works. You are a saint, thank you so much!